# How can I enable search by filename in finder on Lion

Tags: finder, spotlight, search, file

Before switching to Lion (on Snow leopard) I used to open a directory (like my `Downloads`) and start searching using the search box at the top right of the finder window for a file and there was an option to restrict the search to "filenames" only.
The "filename" option does not show up by default for me, is there a way to bring it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add tokens like this by typing `name:` before the search phrase or selecting *Filename contains* from the suggestion list:

[image]

Comment: `name:` does not work for me! but now I noticed that when I start typing a menu appear with an option that says `File name contains ...` if I click on that I get the desired effect.

Comment: @Ali You have to type like `name:search phrase` and then press return. Apple really botched up the UI though.

Comment: Yep, you need to press return and then you'll see it as shown it the picture.